# std::atomic bool or Normal global bool is good in single thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

I have global vaiable in a below thread (bool allow) which  restrict client to wait (by assign allow=false) till it is completed. After completed allow =true

```
bool allow =true;
static void * mythread(void *arg)
{

/* here is  Lock mutex code */

 allow =false;(**non atomic**)

 system(command);

  allow =true;

/* here is Unlock Mutex code */

}



if(allow)
{

// validate thread output

}

else
{
// wait
}
```

**My concern is should i use std::atomic for the global varibale or its good as bove**

```
std::atomic<bool>allow(true);

static void * mythread(void *arg)
{

 /* here is  Lock mutex code */

allow.store(false, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

 system(command);

allow.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

/* here is Unlock Mutex code */

}

if(allow)
{

// validate thread output

}

else
{
// wait
}
```

Comment: atomic operations can be more expensive than non-atomic operations.   Don't use them unless you need them.

Comment: As long as a variable is used in one thread only `bool` is fine (global as well as local). Even if multiple threads do read access only (no modification) a global variable would be fine. As soon as a variable is accessed concurrently in more than one thread (while at least one may change its value during concurrent execution) it should be synchronized. For this, a mutex can be used but for supported types `atomic<>` works as well. Btw. `atomic<>` may use a mutex internally if necessary.

Comment: @tobi303: You may need the mutex to prevent multiple threads invoking the  `command` simultaneously.

Comment: Why is the Boolean variable even global if only the thread uses it?

Comment: @MartinBonner yes you are right. tbh i didnt pay too much attention what the code is doing, because it is so pseudoish.

Comment: @NathanOliver because  many other process is depend on this bool value.

Comment: @NathanOliver, It's always a good idea to ask, "Why is _X_ global?", but the answer should not depend on how many threads use _X_.  "Global" is a lexical scope, and the alternatives to global (e.g., local, instance variable) are also lexical scopes.  Nothing in the language constrains different threads to different lexical scopes.  The programmer may choose to design the program that way, but that may be a poor choice if the program has too many specialized threads.

Comment: @RohiniSingh, Your title says that the `allow` variable is used "in single thread," but in a comment above you say that "many other process" depend on it. What does "many other process" mean?  Are you certain that the variable is only ever accessed by one thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all access to the boolean is protected by a mutex, then it does not matter either way (in terms of correctness).  Use the `atomic<>` or don't.  The correctness of your code will not suffer.

But the *performance might suffer*, other than the fact that you are locking access to something that already has a `mutex` protecting it, `std::atomic<>` has the potential to use a `mutex` under the hood itself.    `std::atomic_flag` however, is guaranteed to be lock-free.  See [the cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) for more.

If you have a single thread accessing that boolean, then no point having any synchronization at all.